# Javascript parentNode is null when changing content innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div table and i change it using AJAX calls, replacing the whole table with innerHTML. When trying to access the table rows with javascript parentNode is set to null.

Comment: Show us some code so we can help you?

Comment: are there any messages on the console ? is the table well-formed after substitution? did you compare the html string that you substitute with to the innerhtml string after substitution? can you access other parts of the table ? more specific ideas will certainly rush in when you post some code ... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTML` removes the old DOM and inserts the new. It's extremely haxy in some ways that make it different from `removeChild`, for instance children of the removed elements are no longer maintained. Generally elements removed by `innerHTML` changes are immediately garbage-collected, unless you happen to have a specific reference to them.

You should either use less "nuke"-like methods to update your data, or ensure you are referencing the new table after the replacement.